# mod_wsgi application entry point? What and Where is it?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to figure out if I have set up my mod_wsgi in Embedded mode or Daemon mode and found this page ["Reloading Source Code"](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode) on the mod_wsgi wiki. It provides a handy script which will tell you what your setup is.

However I'm just not sure about the below sentence from the guide?

> "If you are not sure whether you are using embedded mode or daemon
>   mode, then substitute your WSGI application entry point with sic[the below script]"

What or where is my 'WSGI application entry point'? Where can I copy the script to?

Thanks

- Ubuntu: 12.04.5 LTS
- Apache: 2.2.22
- mod_wsgi Version: 3.3-4ubuntu0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say `WSGI application entry point` is the wsgi.py script which is the Gate (stands also for Gateway) from apache into django app and vise versa

it is like

```
browser < - > server < - > wsgi < - > django
```

without wsgi the server can serve (render) normal html files but not django app. for this, you need wsgi  (Web Server Gateway interface) which is a Gate between django and server

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It means wherever the WSGIServerAlias is pointing to, so for Django the wsgi.py file.